# What is wrong with this code, I am trying to use positions and words in a list to recreate an original sentence that has been split

Tags: python

```
myFile = open("extracted.txt","r") # THIS READS A FILE AND SPLITS TO A LIST
myList = myFile.readlines()
word = myList[0].split(' ')
position = [0]

for  count, i in enumerate(word):        # THIS FINDS THE POSITIONS
    if word.count(i) < 2:
        position.append(max(position) + 1)
    else:
        position.append(word.index(i) + 1)

position.remove(0)    
recreate= []
for count in position:    
    recreate.append(word[count - 1])        # THIS RECREATES ORIGINAL SENTENCE
    with open ("test.txt","w") as file:   # WRITES TO A NEW FILE
        file.write(" ".join(recreate))
        file.close
```

My code prints a sentence similar to the new file , but some words are not in the right order.Sorry I am relatively new to coding.
This is what it is supposed to print to a new file, as read from "extracted.txt":
one, two, three, four, five, five, four, three, two and one.

this is what it actually prints:
one, two, three, four, five, five, four, three, five, four, three,

Comment: please add the output from your script

Comment: Please, post input string, expected output and wrong current output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should replace this line:

```
    position.append(max(position)+1)
```

with:

```
    position.append(count+1)
```

Duplicate words will go to the `else` part and result in an index number that is not higher than the maximum value already in `position`. If then later you have a new word again, it needs to get the correct index, not the maximum value (that did not increase every time).

Comment: thankyou, this has solved the problem, but when i print the positions they seem to be wrong?

Comment: The positions will point to the *first* occurrence of the word. That is how you programmed it. If you don't want that, then always do `position.append(count+1)`, and remove the `if ... else ...` construct. But honestly, then your code becomes so trivial, that it is not clear why you want to do all that, since the end result is what you started with.